# AJAX will post to originating page but not another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script that submits multiple forms using AJAX. It will post the data successfully if the url used is the originating page, but it will not post the data to another page (the page I use for processing).

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
/* AJAX for edit */
    var submitForms = [
                        document.forms["editRow"],
                        document.forms["editRow2"],
                        document.forms["editRow3"],
                        document.forms["editRow4"],
                        document.forms["editRow5"],
                        document.forms["editRow6"],
                        document.forms["editRow7"],
                        document.forms["editRow8"]
                      ] 

    $('.submitEdit').on('click', function() {
        var editRow = $(submitForms).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: "IRCprocessinventory.php",
        data: editRow,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            $('body').html(result);
        } //end result
    }); // end ajax 
    }); // end click
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response on the browser's console?

Comment: Firebug said a request was sent to the processing page, but nothing happened after.

Comment: No response code at all?

Comment: I'm a noob with Firebug, and can't seem to reproduce the message. As far as I can tell there is no response of any kind. However, a successful post to the same page returns this "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/"

Comment: have you tried url: "/IRC/IRCprocessinventory.php" ?

Comment: Are you setting your AJAX requests to be synchronous somewhere?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware... If that's not the default I have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: Is the code you show in IRCprocessinventory.php?

Comment: No, the page is named testchange.php, if I use that as the url I get the response. With the above code nothing is returned.

Comment: hmn... in the url: "IRCprocessinventory.php" use absolute server path to the page name. When you pull up IRCprocessinventory.php on a browser does it have any permission issue?

Comment: in IRCprocessinventory.php can you put print_r($_POST);

Comment: Yes, everything seems to work except if I change the url.

Comment: So, if you copied that exact file with a different name wouldn't work? Or are you adding domain, etc.? What is the change to the url in other words?

Comment: If I use testchange.php (the name of the file) as the ajax url it works well. If I use a different url it doesn't work and I get no response from Firebug.

Comment: firebug is supposed to catch XHR unless nothing is being passed in

Comment: I'll keep playing with it and see if I can figure something out.